# Visual Studio 2019 This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.11. I'm trying to install SentryOne Unit Test Generator. I'm getting an error. Here is the log.

```
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - 17.0.5226-preview5
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - Command line parameters:
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:16.11.31911.196,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\erdal.emlik\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXxxmwobac.vsix
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9.12.2021 20:36:44 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:45 - Initializing Install...
9.12.2021 20:36:45 - Extension Details...
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Identifier         : SentryOne.UnitTestGenerator.4a7063ed-7b9a-4195-a740-9976b84638ea
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Name               : SentryOne Unit Test Generator
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Author             : SentryOne
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Version            : 1.0.35
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Description        : SentryOne Unit Test Generator generates boiler plate unit test code for existing classes.
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    Locale             : en-US
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    MoreInfoURL        : 
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    InstalledByMSI     : False
9.12.2021 20:36:45 -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
9.12.2021 20:36:45 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    SignedBy           : SQL Sentry, LLC
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    Certificate Info   : 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Subject]       : CN="SQL Sentry, LLC", OU=Development, O="SQL Sentry, LLC", L=Charlotte, S=North Carolina, C=US
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Issuer]        : CN=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Serial Number] : 5B6BA1F36A3102BA2D5F04A238BAAE78
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Not Before]    : 22.05.2019 03:00:00
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Not After]     : 22.05.2022 02:59:59
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        [Thumbprint]    : 155957DF2C7F3BA84E7278DF8FAB93C2F9FD26F0
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    Supported Products : 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            Version : [15.0,19.0)
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            ProductArchitecture : notSpecified
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            Version : [15.0,19.0)
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            ProductArchitecture : notSpecified
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            Version : [15.0,19.0)
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -            ProductArchitecture : notSpecified
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    References         : 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Name         : Visual Studio MPF 15.0
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Version      : [15.0]
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        MoreInfoURL  : 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Nested       : No
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    Prerequisites      : 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Name         : Visual Studio core editor
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -        Version      : [15.0,19.0)
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - Signature Details...
9.12.2021 20:36:46 -    Extension is signed with a valid signature.
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - 
9.12.2021 20:36:46 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   konum: VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   konum: VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   konum: VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack, IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
   konum: VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   konum: VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   konum: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   konum: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Özel durumun oluşturulduğu önceki konumdan başlayan yığın izlemesinin sonu ---
   konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

After this error. Installed it from chrome and tried to edit `extension.vsixmanifest` file. Edited the installation part like this

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false" AllUsers="true">
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
</Installation>
```

At first installed it but nothing happened on visual studio side. After, this time changed and tested the system where it is located but  i got another error and log file completely changed.

```
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - 17.0.5226-preview5
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - Command line parameters:
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\erdal.emlik\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXgxkcrz0r.vsix,/callingprocessid:12452,/installas:2900
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9.12.2021 20:50:41 - -------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - Initializing Install...
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - Uzantı Ayrıntıları...
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Identifier         : SentryOne.UnitTestGenerator.4a7063ed-7b9a-4195-a740-9976b84638ea
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Name               : SentryOne Unit Test Generator
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Author             : SentryOne
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Version            : 1.0.35
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Description        : SentryOne Unit Test Generator generates boiler plate unit test code for existing classes.
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Locale             : en-US
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    MoreInfoURL        : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    InstalledByMSI     : False
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    SignatureState     : UnSupportedCryptographicAlgorithm
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    SignedBy           : SQL Sentry, LLC
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Certificate Info   : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Subject]       : CN="SQL Sentry, LLC", OU=Development, O="SQL Sentry, LLC", L=Charlotte, S=North Carolina, C=US
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Issuer]        : CN=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Serial Number] : 5B6BA1F36A3102BA2D5F04A238BAAE78
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Not Before]    : 22.05.2019 03:00:00
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Not After]     : 22.05.2022 02:59:59
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        [Thumbprint]    : 155957DF2C7F3BA84E7278DF8FAB93C2F9FD26F0
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Desteklenen Ürünler : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            Version : [14.0,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            ProductArchitecture : x86
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            Version : [14.0,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            ProductArchitecture : x86
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            Version : [12.0,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            ProductArchitecture : x86
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            Version : [14.0,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            ProductArchitecture : x86
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            Version : [14.0,)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -            ProductArchitecture : x86
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Başvurular         : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Name         : Visual Studio MPF 15.0
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Version      : [15.0]
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        MoreInfoURL  : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Nested       : No
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Önkoşullar         : 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        -------------------------------------------------------
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Name         : Visual Studio core editor
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -        Version      : [15.0,19.0)
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - İmza ayrıntıları...
9.12.2021 20:50:42 -    Extension is signed with an unsupported algorithm.
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - 
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - Uygun ürünler aranıyor...
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - Bulunan yüklü ürün - Genel Konum
9.12.2021 20:50:42 - Bulunan yüklü ürün - Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0svlcpc5.1bz\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0ufvjvfw.v4w\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\1fseqwi5.c1l\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2b2vfgaj.pv1\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\4aqbw2fi.ogl\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\4hxf43nx.gv1\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\5pgtybsx.kzx\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\ai52hjuu.a43\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\anyvp0u0.xdj\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\aqwf5fqp.2lv\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\cfz2jtpw.lsc\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\edljzsai.0ow\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\esiuwmsy.sg3\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\feb0tx3k.wnx\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\fks51mw5.ddq\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\ha3gujbo.tie\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\hpfov5b4.ecb\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\hvjzahq4.r0w\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\j3vc5x1h.duc\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\lnn5s4pq.4xk\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\mfxsuemx.tlr\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\n02snpa1.o5j\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\odfln1eo.n4h\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\pnbf2yz4.1ye\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\qnd4ws1k.3yr\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\rahssdlq.j5o\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\rv5ofgut.3dm\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\spmhudae.wp5\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TestPlatform\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\txxba55a.20s\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\uouhc5gr.pk2\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\vhuo0w5y.glt\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\VSSDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\xkwg23bq.qvm\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\xt54bhr0.qqm\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\zld3m31d.vpp\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClickOnce\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ConnectedServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DebugAdapterHost\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DebuggerServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\IntelliCode\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\IntelliCode.CSharp\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\LiveShare\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\LiveShare.VSCore\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedProjectSystem\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Microsoft Office 365 Connected Service\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Portable Library Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Publish\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TemplateEngine\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WCF Connected Service\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Live Preview\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools Shared\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools Diagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ADL Tools\2.6.1000.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\AppInsights\Contracts\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\AppInsights\Core\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeSense\Framework\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ConnectedServices\Authentication\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Modeling\16.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLDB\SSDTUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLDB\Vsix\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLEditor\Vsix\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestTools\Fakes\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Unit Test Explorer\TestWIExtension\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\10.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\11.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\12.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\14.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Azure\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Library Manager\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Common\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Deployment Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\RemoteDebugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Resource Manager\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\SnapshotViewer\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Azure\Package\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Azure\WebJobs\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\DataDesign\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\AnalyzeCodeCoverage\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CallHierarchy\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodingConventions\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Commands\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CrossRepositorySearch\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DesignTools\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ErrorList\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\FSharp\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\InteractiveWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\LanguageServer\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NavigateTo\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NuGet\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NuGetRecommender\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\OpenFolder\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Performance Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProjectServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProjectSystemQuery\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\RazorLanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ReferenceManager\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Search\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Terminal\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TextMate\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TypeScript\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows.Forms\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlLanguageService\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\CPUSampling\extension.vsixmanifest'
9.12.2021 20:50:55 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Database\extension.vsixmanifest'
```

..And more

I know it looks little bit scary but soory about that. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into something very similar with one of the extensions I maintain. Based on your log, it looks like you also have Visual Studio 2022 installed, as the `vsixinstaller.exe` version is `17.0.X`. The supported versions for the extension you are trying to install are listed as 15.0 up to, but not including, 19.0.

Starting with Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.x), all extensions must be compiled as 64-bit extensions. I think there is some sort of check that is made as part of the VSIX installation to ensure that this extension can, in fact, be installed on Visual Studio 2022 - which means it must be a 64-bit extension.

The fix, for me, was to update the `InstallationTarget` version attributes to stop at version 17.0, so in your case you would update the versions in the `extension.vsixmanifest` file to be:

```xml
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false" AllUsers="true">
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0, 17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0, 17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[12.0, 17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0, 17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0, 17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
</Installation>
```

After I updated the manifest file in the VSIX I was able to install this extension using the updated `VSIXInstaller.exe` application that was installed when Visual Studio 2022 was installed.

Comment: This helped me to modify another VS 2019 extension that wouldn't install while VS 2022 was present.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the slow answer... I wrote that extension - but I don't have access to update it any more. I have, however, re-worked it as https://github.com/mattwhitfield/Unitverse - which is a much better version based on the same code.

In addition to the other answer, you'd want to remove the signing from the package - VSIX packages are really finickity about signing. For Unitverse I'm not backed by a company, so I just ship it unsigned.